# Synonym request for MKMapKit

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

I would like to request a synonym for a tag on the main site, [mkmapkit](/questions/tagged/mkmapkit), because people are using this tag to talk about the Apple iOS [Map Kit framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html). But that framework is not called `MKMapKit`. It is just `Map Kit`.

Yes, all of the Map Kit framework classes, protocols and functions start with the `MK` prefix (e.g. `MKMapView`, `MKAnnotation`, etc.), but there's no such thing as `MKMapKit` and to refer to it as such is a misnomer. In the iOS world, it would be equivalent to referring to "Core Location Framework" as the "CLCoreLocation framework" (which, of course, it's not).

There is another, well established tag, [mapkit](/questions/tagged/mapkit), which could be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. You're right, the MKMapKit thing always bothered me.